# Hiding raw_input() password input

Tags: python, masking, raw-input

I want to hide my password but I don't know how. I have seen `show="*"` and also `getpass` but I don't know how to place them into this code. I'm using Python 2.7.3 and coding on a Raspberry Pi.

```
ans = True

while ans:
    print("""
                   -------------
                  | 1. Shutdown | 
                  | 2. Items    |
                   -------------
    """)

    ans=raw_input("""

             Please Enter A Number: """)

    if ans == "1":

        exit()
    elif ans == "2":


        pa=raw_input("""

             Please Enter Password: """)

        if pa == "zombiekiller":

            print("""
                   ----------------
                  | 1. Pi password |
                  | 2. Shutdown    |
                   ----------------
            """)

            pe=raw_input ("""

             Please Enter A Number: """)

            if pe == "1":
                print ("""

             Pi's Password Is Adminofpi""")
                import time
                time.sleep(1)
                exit()

            elif pe == "2":
                exit()

            else:
                print("""

             You Have Entered An Inccoredt Option. Terminating Programm""")
                import time
                time.sleep(1)
                exit()

        else:
                print("""

             You Have Entered An Inccorect Password. Terminating Programm""")
                import time
                time.sleep(1)
                exit()
```

Comment: Use [getpass.getpass()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass#getpass.getpass).

Answer (score 64):

`getpass` hides the input, just replace `raw_input` after importing the module `getpass`, like this:

```
import getpass
.
.
.
pa = getpass.getpass()
```

Comment: Be aware that sometimes this will yield `Warning: password may be echoed` if you are running this from IDLE.